# Manga. Main characters clear the world and wake up in the future real world

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for a manga I have read before. The main character lives in a fantasy world or something. When he and everyone else clear the main quest or defeated the boss. They wake up in the real world in the future. The fake world was only training for be able to save the humanity or something.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Do you recall how many chapters it takes for the main character to clear the main quest? Does this happen in the first chapter, or does it take around 60 chapters?

Comment: I not remember so much. I read it online but not remember where. I think it was mostly black and white. And it was more like 60 or something before they clear everything.

Comment: Was the main character an extremely powerful villager instead of a standard game-like class of "warrior" or "mage" or anything? Does that sound familiar?

Comment: Yes that sounds familiar.

Comment: I'll write up an answer. It'll take a bit to find the actual wakeup scene; I forget the exact chapter.

Answer (score 4):

This is *[LV999 no Murabito](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/lv999-no-murabito)*, aka *Level 999 Villager*.

> In this world, the concept of levels exist. Other than those who live off defeating monsters, most people are only around Level 1 to 5. What's more, not just anyone can go out to hunt monsters; it's heavily influenced by one's role appointed by God. There are eight such eligible roles. Those blessed with extraordinary power are divided into three types. But for the majority of the population, they have no such powers and live by farming or running shops. Towns are developed by those with the weakest role... Villagers. For the powerless Villagers going out to hunt monsters is equivalent to committing suicide. But one day, a certain two-year-old child given the role of Villager notices something. Once you defeat a monster... you can earn great wealth.

The synopsis only covers the fantasy world part. It's a typically game-like world with monsters that give money and experience points, and a demon king. Defeating the demon king is one part of the main quest mentioned in comments. The main characters is friends with the demon king and is perfectly capable of defeating him, but refuses to do so.

Much later in the story, specifically Volume 9, he and his companions complete the "main quest" through another route. This results in them moving on to the next stage - the real world. The real world had been destroyed by some invading force, with only certain "mutant" people able to fight back; these were the basis for the combat classes mentioned in the synopsis.

[image: Waking up in the next stage] [image: Japan]